# "nested" or with multiple values

Tags: sql, nested

So I'm a new SQL user and am stuck on whether or not there's a way to do this so any help would be appreciated.
this code works:

```
select *
from    ADMIN.ASSOCIATE_TBL A
where   (A.termination_date between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31'
      or A.Start_date between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31'
      or A.Rehire_date between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31')
      and employee_id='802740'
```

what I want to know is is there a way to combine the search fields with the date range? Look at the below code for the "thought process" but I know it doesn't work.

```
select *
from    ADMIN.ASSOCIATE_TBL A
where (a.termination_date or a.start_date or a.rehire_date) between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31'
and employee_id='802740'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (add_months is a product specific function.)

Comment: No idea.  I changed the question so the focus is on the thought vs the date range syntax.

Comment: I don't know of any SQL dialect that would allow this (luckily).

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: start_date='2021-04-01', rehire_date='2021-04-03' termination_date='2021-05-05' logic tests if any of the three dates falls between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31' and returns true/false.  objective is shorter way to request checking all three dates simultaneously vs (start_date between x/y or rehire_date between x/y or termination_date between x/y)